# MySQL Problems Bigger =Slower?

Tags: mysql

Please bear with me, I'm not overly confident with MySQL coding.
I am running a site that is similar to twitter. However, it seems the more followers a user gets, the slower the site runs on that particular user profile.
A user with few followers has a reasonably fast page load.

Below is the "Follower" part of the MySQL, can any of you see a problem with the code or shed any light as to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `followers` (
    `id`        int(10)       unsigned            NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `follower`  int(11)       unsigned            NOT NULL,
    `following` int(10)       unsigned            NOT NULL,
    `status`    enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8  NOT NULL  DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 Trash, 1 Active',
    `date`      timestamp                         NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `follower` (`follower`,`following`,`status`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Any problems are more likely due to your query than your table structure. So post the queries to retrieve the data, please, along with the [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) output

Comment: Thank you. At the risk of sounding stupid, where would I be able to look at the queries?

Comment: @AndyH: did you write the code for this site or are you just doing DB maintenance?

Comment: Hi - no, it is part of a bought script. I am trying to figure out why it slows down when a user has many "followers"

Answer (score 1):

first thing, why are you using MyISAM engine for a table that is constantly being updated, this slows down your app as MyISAM uses table level locks, meaning selects have to wait for inserts to be done for them to run, always use InnoDB for such tables.

second thing I think it would be better to use a key for each of `follower` and `following` because now any query that is like `WHERE following=X` won't use your index `follower`

If you can show a sample of your `SELECTS`, maybe you'll get some more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought about using InnoDB, but the MySQL is part of a bought script (so you'd think it was right!) I did change it to InnoDB, but it made no difference? I'm not at all clued up on this kind of stuff, so everything I do is trial and error at the moment. Would the full MySQL provided with the script help?

Comment: @AndyH no, just show us some of your `SELECTS`. then depending on that people will suggest if they want to see the full script or not. As for innoDB even if you didn't see any difference directly, I can tell you that for such table it is 1000% better.

Comment: CodeBird, I know this sounds ridiculous, but what are SELECTS? I really am new to this kind of thing.

Comment: CodeBird - you want snippets of the HTML? *sorry for sounding stupid

Comment: @AndyH no, not html, PHP or whatever language that is interacting with MySQL. something like `SELECT * FROM followers WHERE ...`

Comment: @AndyH: You need to learn the basics before trying to optimize. At this point, we really *shouldn't* be helping you because you don't even know about `SELECT` statements. How can you possibly know what you need to understand to fix performance problems? Learn some basic SQL and come back when you know something about the problem domain.

Comment: I agree. I really do need to get to know and understand SQL. Sorry for wasting peoples time. I'll go and learn about it. Thanks.